# Authenticating only works once

Tags: python, sockets, openvpn

I am manually authenticating clients by management interface over a Unix domain socket (well by a python script).

```
while True:
    # get something of queue and parse it
    command = "client-auth-nt " + data[2] + " " + data[3] + "\r\n"
    out.write(command)
    out.flush()
```

This only works for one client, once. After I have connected once and successfully authenticated I cannot connect with any other client or reconnect unless I restart the OpenVPN server.

```
ERROR: client-auth command failed
```

What is going on? This is giving me headaches.

Comment: What's `data`, and how does it change from iteration to iteration?

Comment: Data are environment variables from the OpenVPN management interface received through the socket on connection, disconnect, reestablish events. In this case, the specific vars are KID and CID, 2 ids generated to identify a cliënt connection. I'm parsing them from socket input and they get put on the queue.

Comment: I'm going to double check the values since I feel you're pointing in that direction. The KID is always 0 which is normal. CID is an incremental client identifier and ensured to be always unique.

Comment: Okay, but nothing in your code causes `data` to change each time the loop runs.

Comment: See my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A good night sleep and some coffee made me notice the fault was indeed in the data array. I switched the position of two variables by accident. Much thanks to Chris for pointing in the right direction.